# If loop to ignore null value for conditional checks

Tags: if-statement, terraform

```
locals {

  acl_out = flatten([
    for opi, clsan in var.appr : [
      for co, coo in clsan : [
        for applo in coo : [
           for op in ( co == "RO" ? ["READ","DESCRIBE"] : ["WRITE"]) : {
             oper = op
             appid_lo = applo
             opic-name = opi
             process = co
             
           }

        ]
      ]

    ]
  ])

}
```

```
variable "appr" {
  description = "A complex object "
  type = map(object({
    #displayname = string

      RO  = optional(list(string))
      WO    = optional(list(string)) 

    
  }))
}
```

- If `co = RO  then ["READ","DESCRIBE"]`
- If `co = WO  then [WRITE]`

Above expression fails with `null` value, If `WO` not defined/unset in product 2, If statement need to corrected

Input :

Working

```
appr = {
  product1 = { WO = ["6470"], RO = ["6471","5538"] },
  product2 = { WO = ["5555"], RO = ["6472"]}, 
  product3 = { WO = ["6473"], RO = ["6474"] },
}
```

Not Working

```
appr = {
  product1 = { WO = ["6470"], RO = ["6471","5538"] },
  product2 = { RO = ["6472"]},
  product3 = { WO = ["6473"], RO = ["6474"] },
}
```

Error:

`A null value cannot be used as the collection in a 'for' expression.`

Tried this way also fails

```
for op in ( co == "RO" = ["READ","DESCRIBE"] || co == "WO" = ["WRITE"] ) :  {
```

Desired Result :

```
{
   opic-name = "product1"
   oper = "WRITE"
   appid_lo = 6470
},
{
   opic-name = "product1"
   oper = "READ"
   appid_lo = 6471
},
 {
   opic-name = "product1"
   oper = "DESCRIBE"
   appid_lo = 6471
}
```

and so on

Comment: Uhm, where is `co` coming from? What is that supposed to be?

Comment: this does not look like any valid HCL i wonder how it only fails with the message posted and not with a lot of syntax error?

could you paste the complete code you tried to make it reproducible.

what is the desired result?

Comment: added additional info @mariux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was a fun one!

Check if it is null before running the next for

```
locals {
  acl_out = flatten([
    for opi, clsan in var.appr : [
      for co, coo in clsan : [
        coo == null ? [] : [
        for applo in coo : [
           for op in ( co == "RO" ? ["READ","DESCRIBE"] : ["WRITE"]) : {
             oper = op
             appid_lo = applo
             opic-name = opi
             process = co
           }
        ]
      ]]
    ]
  ])
}
```

Output for acl_out

```
acl_out = [
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "6471"
          + oper      = "READ"
          + opic-name = "product1"
          + process   = "RO"
        },
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "6471"
          + oper      = "DESCRIBE"
          + opic-name = "product1"
          + process   = "RO"
        },
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "5538"
          + oper      = "READ"
          + opic-name = "product1"
          + process   = "RO"
        },
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "5538"
          + oper      = "DESCRIBE"
          + opic-name = "product1"
          + process   = "RO"
        },
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "6470"
          + oper      = "WRITE"
          + opic-name = "product1"
          + process   = "WO"
        },
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "6472"
          + oper      = "READ"
          + opic-name = "product2"
          + process   = "RO"
        },
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "6472"
          + oper      = "DESCRIBE"
          + opic-name = "product2"
          + process   = "RO"
        },
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "6474"
          + oper      = "READ"
          + opic-name = "product3"
          + process   = "RO"
        },
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "6474"
          + oper      = "DESCRIBE"
          + opic-name = "product3"
          + process   = "RO"
        },
      + {
          + appid_lo  = "6473"
          + oper      = "WRITE"
          + opic-name = "product3"
          + process   = "WO"
        },
    ]
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Leo, I figured out the null value. My code works